# PowerShell Start-Process not setting $lastexitcode

Tags: powershell

I have a set of test DLL's that I'm running from a powershell script that calls OpenCover.Console.exe via the `Start-Process` command.

I have the `-returntargetcode` flag set

After execution I check `$lastexitcode` and `$?`. They return 1 and True respectively all the time. Even when tests are failing.

Shouldn't `$lastexitcode` be 0 when all tests pass and 1 when they fail?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, `Start-Process` is asynchronous, so it doesn't wait for your process to exit.  If you want your command-line tool to run synchronously, drop the `Start-Process` and invoke the command directly.   That's the only way it will set `$LASTEXITCODE`.    For example, causing CMD.exe to exit with a 2:

```
cmd /c exit 2
$LASTEXITCODE
```

You can make `Start-Process` synchronous by adding the `-Wait` flag, but it still wont' set `$LASTEXITCODE`.  To get the ExitCode from `Start-Process` you add `-PassThru` to your `Start-Process`, which then outputs a `[System.Diagnostics.Process]` object which you can use to monitor the process, and (eventually) get access to its `ExitCode` property. Here's an example that should help:

```
$p = Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c exit 2" -PassThru -Wait
$p.ExitCode
```

Of course the advantage of this approach is you don't need to wait for the process, but later when it exits you have the information about it's run in `$p`.

Comment: It was the -PassThru that fixed it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When executing a GUI application, dropping the `Start-Process` does not help, as PowerShell does not wait for GUI application to complete, when executing them directly this way. So `$LASTEXITCODE` is not set.

Piping the (non existing) GUI application output helps, as it makes PowerShell to wait for the application to complete.

```
notepad.exe | Out-Null
echo $LASTEXITCODE
```

*Note that "GUI application" does not necessarily mean that the application has windows. Whether an application is GUI or console is a flag in .exe file header.*

---

`Start-Process -PassThru -Wait` as suggested in the answer by @Burt_Harris works too in this case, it's just a bit more complicated.