# How to get the exitcode when execute .cmd using powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, exit-code

I have a PS script then need to execute CMD file.
This is how I executed it.

```
$Executing = Start-Process "$PathHome\File.CMD" -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized -ArgumentList "$PathLog","$LogName","$Folder","$Name"
$Exitcode = $Executinig.ExitCode
Write-Host $Exitcode
```

But it return empty. Anyone can help  me please, Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding -passthrough to the end of your start process command. That should pass the information into the variable for you

Comment: You may start the executable `CMD` with the argument `/c $PathHome\File.CMD` to run your batch file.

Comment: @JonathanWaring yeah. It supposed to add "-PassThrue"

Comment: The correct [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) is `-PassThru`. Anyway, for a batch file I wouldn't use `Start-Process` but the call operator: `& "$PathHome\File.CMD" $PathLog $LogName $Folder $Name`. Exit code can be obtained from `$LASTEXITCODE`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Start-Process not setting $lastexitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496829/powershell-start-process-not-setting-lastexitcode)

Comment: Write, `echo %errorlevel%` in your batch and just use the `-PassThrough` parameter. If you'd like see see it from within the batch file itself